# how to pass variables to another activity using intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to build a simple cookie clicker- you press a button a variable grows by 1.
Now, I'm trying to build a shop, so you can buy upgrades-the variable grows more, auto clicks...
So, I'm trying to pass my variables (number of cookies, cookies for click) using intent, but every time I try to get to the activity, my app crash.
here is my MainActivity code:

```
public static int NumOfCookies=0;
public static int CookieForClick=1;
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.cookieclicker01";
public final static String EXTRA_INTENT = "com.example.cookieclicker01";

public void GetToShop(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShopActivity.class);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, NumOfCookies);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_INTENT, CookieForClick);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

here is my code for the second activity:

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
     var1= intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
     var2 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_INTENT);
    NumOfCookies= Integer.parseInt(var1);
    CookiesForClick= Integer.parseInt(var2);
    TextView t1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Cookies);
    t1.setText(Integer.toString(NumOfCookies));
```

Comment: What does your LogCat say? It will tell you why your app crashed.

Comment: why you are adding an empty bundle?

Comment: Isn't your problem was solved by my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a String, but your  var1 , and var2 are int values.

```
var1= intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
 var2 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_INTENT);
```

The correct is :

```
var1= intent.getInt(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
var2 = intent.getInt(MainActivity.EXTRA_INTENT);
```

Or your will change the type of var1, var2 to String:

```
public static String NumOfCookies=0;
public static String CookieForClick=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

either this -

```
//Bundle extras = new Bundle();
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, NumOfCookies);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_INTENT, CookieForClick);
//intent.putExtras(extras);
```

Comment out those two lines. Basically you were putting a empty Bundle in your intent in the last line and thus replacing your previously stored values.

or that-

```
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, NumOfCookies);
    extras.putString(EXTRA_INTENT, CookieForClick);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
```